I can't start a virtual device in Android Studio on Ubuntu, what can be done?
I am trying to run a virtual device in Android Studio. No matter which device I select or what settings I choose, be that hardware or software graphics etc or whether I run it from the AS GUI or command line I keep getting the same error:
$ emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Medium_Phone_API_35 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
[29408:29408:20241121,104652.011792:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[29408:29408:20241121,104652.013055:WARNING process_reader_linux.cc:144] no stack mapping
[1]    29406 segmentation fault (core dumped)  emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Medium_Phone_API_35    300

or
$ emulator -list-avds
[29439:29439:20241121,104722.185855:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[29439:29439:20241121,104722.187049:WARNING process_reader_linux.cc:144] no stack mapping
[1]    29437 segmentation fault (core dumped)  emulator -list-avds

It is a fresh setup precisely by React Native guidelines: https://reactnative.dev/docs/set-up-your-environment
What on Earth am I doing wrong? How can this be diagnosed further? Please help.
Context:

Android Studio:

Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-242.23339.11.2421.12550806, built on October 24, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
Linux 6.8.0-49-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
  i18n.locale=
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME


OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-8700 × 12, VT-d enabled
Nvidia driver: Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-550
Packages installed:

Android SDK Platform 34
Sources for Android 34
Intel x86_64 Atom System Image
Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image
Android SDK Build-Tools 36-rx1 35.0.0, 34.0.0
Android Emulator 35.2.10
Android SDK Platform Tools


Java

$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.12 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-17.0.12+1-1087.25-jcef (build 17.0.12+1-b1087.25)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-17.0.12+1-1087.25-jcef (build 17.0.12+1-b1087.25, mixed mode)

